# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called upon user granting permission to receive push notifications

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

I've setup didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in AppDelegate like so:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format:"%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken got called - Token is: \(token)")
        // delegate might get called even before an authtoken has been set for the user. Return in such cases:
        guard UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authtoken") != nil else {return}

        // otherwise continue:
        if (token != UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "apnsToken")) {
            self.apiService.setAPNSToken(apnsToken: token, completion: {result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let resultString):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "apnsToken")
                        print(resultString, " Token is: \(token)")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("An error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("User is registered for Push Notifications. Token did not change and is: \(token)")
        }

    }
```

I'm asking for user permission to sent push Notifications in one of my view controllers like so:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if (granted) {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "pushNotificationsEnabled")
                }
                print("permission granted?: \(granted)")
            }
        }
```

All pretty standard I suppose. My confusion / problem is this:
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken does not get called upon user interaction - i.e. I would expect it to be called as soon as the user taps on "allow push notifications" so that the apns token would be stored on my back end. But it doesn't.
When I close the app down and start it again, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken gets called and the token gets stored on the back end.

What do I need to do in order to access the token and store it in the backend upon user having tapped on "allow push notifications"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your user confirms that they want notifications you should call `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()`. It doesn't seem like you are doing this.

You could do something like this

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
  .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
    [weak self] granted, error in

    print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
    guard granted else { return }
    self?.getNotificationSettings()
}
```

Then `getNotificationSettings` checks that it has been authorised before registering for remote notifications.

```
func getNotificationSettings() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
    print("Notification settings: \(settings)")

    guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
  }
}
```

For more on how to handle push notifications check out this [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started).